# Which stats test--MANOVA or Mixed Effects?

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, manova

I need to see if there's a statistical difference for each ID between CHLA, CWBA, and CH and what that difference is, AS WELL AS, if Species Type is a factor. Which R package would do this? I have the following data:

```r
ID    Species_Type Total…¹ Hairl…² Mass_…³ `%_fur` CHL1  CHL2  CHLA CWBA CH
   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 XLM1  Extra Large…    32.5    32.0 0.5320… 1.6358… -21.… -21.… -21.… -21.…
 2 XLM2  Extra Large…    42.9    42.7 0.1480… 0.3452… -21.… -21.… -22.… -21.…
 3 XLM3  Extra Large…    35.1    34.9 0.2040… 0.5809… -22.… -22.… -22.2 -22.…
 4 XLM4  Extra Large…    44.1    43.7 0.3661… 0.8313… -21.… -21.… -21.… -21.…
 5 XLM5  Extra Large…    34.8    34.2 0.6349… 1.8228… -22.… -22.… -22.1 -22.…
 6 XLMA  Extra Large…    37.9    37.5 0.3770… 1.0432… -21.… -22.… -22.… -22.…
 7 GP1   Guinea Pig      80.3    78.6 1.7070… 2.1247… -25.… -24.5 -25.… -25.…
 8 GP2   Guinea Pig      60.7    59.7 0.9440… 1.5558… -24.… -25.… -25.… -25.…
 9 GP3   Guinea Pig      50.5    49.4 1.0670… 2.1122… -25.… -26.7 -26.… -26.…
10 GP4   Guinea Pig      77.4    76.0 1.4609… 1.8872… -24.… -25.… -24.… -24.…
```

I'm super new to R and stats so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: https://quantitudepod.org/s2e09-manova-must-die/ (not MANOVA, is what I'm saying)

Comment: Okay, sold---but what test *do* I use?

Comment: I don't think you've given enough detail for me to answer confidently. But it looks like I'd use lmer() from the lme4 package.